# Auto generate JHipster entities from existing database

Tags: entity-framework, reverse-engineering, jhipster

As part of JHispster 2.11.0, the entity configuration is saved in a specific .json file, in the .jhipster directory. These files can be used to regenerate entities and related files in JHipster application using the below command.

yo jhipster:entity ENTITY_NAME

Is there any way to auto generate those .json files from existing database?

Answer (score 6):

We are currently working to generate those files from a UML model, see our [JHipster UML](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-uml) project.

So if you can export your database schema to UML, this could be doable, but I don't think this can work as smoothly as expected.

Comment: Thank you @julien-dubois for you answer and the very good JHipster project. I tried Modelio as per the above link and I am able to create class diagram and generate XMI out of it. I have tested that XMI file in JHipster and it has created the tables as per the class diagram.

Comment: But my problem is that I have an existing database with lot of tables and I am trying to reverse engineer the tables to class diagram through Modelio, but there is no such provision.  Using Visual Paragigm I am able to reverse engineer the tables to class diagrams. But I have exported the class diagram in to XMI file, but it generated a different content when compared to XMI file generated through Modelio and also it did not work in JHipster.

Comment: Can you let me know the process to reverse engineer tables to class diagram and then class diagram to XMI file. If this is not possible how about querying the metadata of the database and generate entity json files which can be directly used by JHipster. Please suggest.

Comment: Any news in the meanwhile regarding this? I have more or less the same problem (existing database, need to create a new application), tried the reverse engineering with Modelio, UML designer and Visual Paradigm but I'm having issues with all 3 (first with the reverse engineering, then with the import using jhipster-uml). My schema is rather large (>80 tables) so (re)creating the entities is not really an option. I'm wondering if writing a module which generates the JDL files directly from a DDL or a live connection would make sense, or not.