# jHipster import database schema

Tags: jhipster

I am new to `JHipster`. I am creating new `JHipster` project, but I was wondering if I can generate all entities from my current `Oracle` tables/schema.

Is it possible? I tried [db-helper plugin](https://github.com/bastienmichaux/generator-jhipster-db-helper) but it does not seem to have this feature.

Looks like it only needs to create JDL file from existing database.

Answer (score 1):

As specified in the [motivation of the db-helper plugin](https://github.com/bastienmichaux/generator-jhipster-db-helper/blob/master/whatAndWhy.md) JHipster is using some convention and depending on how consistent you designed your database, i.e. name of tables, name of PK etc; it can be more or less difficult to start JHipster on an already existing database. As specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30390545/auto-generate-jhipster-entities-from-existing-database) you could try to create a UML from your schema and use [JHipster UML](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-uml) to generate a JHipster project based on your schema. The problem is that there are no tools, at least no free tools from what you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503/reverse-engineer-oracle-schema-to-erd).

Depending on how many tables you have, you could try to read the metadata from your DB and generate the jdl  file at least for the entities and their properties. For the relation it can be a little complicated.